# How to insert a logo into cvevent function from Altacv template?

Tags: logos, altacv

I found an interesting CV model on LateX which uses AltaCV style.

AltaCV_template(https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/altacv-template/trgqjpwnmtgv)

I’d like to make it more impactful and insert the logo of a company in cvevent function.

I already tried to use the photoR function and chatGPT to solve this issue but nothing is working on. I wanted to insert includegraphicxs function or photoR on the #5.

```
\newcommand{\cvevent}[5]{%
 {\large\color{emphasis}#1 #5\par}
  \smallskip\normalsize
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2}\par
  \smallskip}
  \ifstrequal{#3}{}{}{%
    {\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth [l]%  {\BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,ActualText={\datename:}}\cvDateMarker\EndAccSupp{}%
  ~#3}%
}}%
  \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{%
    {\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]%
  {\BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,ActualText={\locationname:}}\cvLocationMarker\EndAccSupp{}%
    ~#4}%
}}\par
  \medskip\normalsize
}
```

I tried to insert includegraphicxs in cvevent but it shows the same pic on every cvevent of the code …

This is my first question here. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Where are you stuck? To insert some logo in the `\cvevent` block, just redefine it and use `\includegraphics` in the 5th argument.